# Moving Chrome's extensions folder

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Somehow I've managed to end up with my extensions folder for Chrome on my desktop, which is less than ideal (happened while downgrading from the dev build to the beta build).

I've done a fair bit of Googling on how to get it back to where it should be, to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea how to easily put it back into Chrome's folder structure?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Like, ever. :) Would you mind filing a bug at http://new.crbug.com/ and posting the ID here?The dev version (and beta versions) are explicitly unsupported, and downgrading doubly so (the team reserves the right to make backward-incompatible changes to the profile format), but nothing should move your extensions folder to your desktop. That's just odd.

Comment: Aye, I'll do that when I get home tonight (at work atm). With the unsupported bit, yeah fair enough there :) It doesn't seem particularly beta/dev-specific to move the exts folder to a new location, so I figured I might get some luck from asking

Comment: Right. My point was simply that downgrading isn't a scenario we support, test, etc. It shouldn't move your extensions folder, but we don't really make any promises about it not blowing up. :)